# Google Android Analytics not showing data in web portal

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics

I've had Google Analytics setup for 72 hours now and still no data in the google analytics web portal. Also no real time data.

I am getting successful tracker dispatches (note: I removed my analytic ID and replaced with UA-xxxxxxx-xx).

```
01-18 11:03:38.031: V/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(615): Called dispatch
01-18 11:03:38.052: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(615): Host: www.google-analytics.com
01-18 11:03:38.052: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(615): User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/1.4.2 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; en-us; sdk Build/MR1)
01-18 11:03:38.052: I/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(615): GET /__utm.gif?utmwv=4.8.1ma&utmn=153554207&utmt=event&utme=5(Exposure%20Fragment*Toggle%20Click*Printed%20Photo)(0)&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1238x752&utmul=en-US&utmac=UA-xxxxxxx-xx&utmcc=__utma%3D1.545766597.1358368304.1358377186.1358533440.6%3B&utmht=1358535803519&utmqt=14534 HTTP/1.1
01-18 11:03:38.061: V/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(615): Scheduled next dispatch
01-18 11:03:38.061: V/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(615): Sending 1 hits to dispatcher
01-18 11:03:38.211: V/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(615): HTTP Response Code: 200
```

Currently at a lost for what might be wrong. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I finally fixed the problem after a week.

For those with similar problems here is how I fixed it.

I was using Google Analytics v1.4.2 (which still works properly) however, inside of the Google analytics web portal I had created a new property as an App. What I have found is App properties in Google analytics requires Google analytics V2 (beta) along with the use of the EasyTracker method. So despite v1.4.2 analytics properly contacting google and me getting HTTP 200 response codes back, my best guess is on Google's side they weren't handling the data inputed from v1.4.2 for the new Property App.

To sum it up, use google analytics v2 as well as create a new Property App (NOT WEB PROPERTY) with the EasyTracker methods. Or you can use google analytics v1.4.2 with the "old style" of creating a "fake" web property and using that Unique ID for tracking.

Using analytics v2 is recommend by Google.

Hopefully this helps a few people and you don't pull your hair out like I did trying to figure this one out.